# Jquery panning slider - Image width based on screen resolution

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins, slider, fullscreen

I am trying to use a popular panning slider [Jquery Panning Slider](http://s3.amazonaws.com/buildinternet/live-tutorials/panning-slideshow/panning-slideshow.htm)
for a website.

The markup structure , css and jquery are explained here :- [Slider Details](http://buildinternet.com/2010/02/animate-panning-slideshow-with-jquery/)

This current slider works in a way where it takes only  predefined numeric inputs for width of both the slider container div and ul(where all the images are called from). This makes it difficult to use in scenarios where images can take up the entire browser view port instead of the predefined width and height. I want to make the slider take up the entire viewport for screen resolutions upto 1600px in width.

The images that I want to use in the slider are of 1600px in width and 804px in height which I want to be scaled as per the aspect ratio and browser screen size on different screens.

After I googled and went through some of the web pages , All I understood was 
$(window).width() 

 needs to be used somewhere in the pages. Beyond that I'm stuck. Can somebody help me .. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try the responsive slider instead. there are lots of jquery free plugins to do this job..